# Remove another div when a div is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the loading image when the `.flexslider` div is loaded but the jquery (`$('flexslider').load()`) is not working. How to remove the image when the div is completely loaded?

index.html

```
<div class="flexslider">
        <div class="loadingDiv">
            <img src="images/banner0.jpg" style="visibility:hidden"/>
            <div class="showbox">

                <div class="loader">
                    <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">

                        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>                           
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>                                              
            <ul class="slides">
                <li><img src="images/banner1.jpg" width="1000px" height="500px" alt="" class="animated fadeInRightBig">
                    <div class="txtoverlay">
                        <div class="centralise">
                            <div class="verticalwrap">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="images/banner2.png" alt="">
                    <div class="txtoverlay">
                        <div class="centralise">
                            <div class="verticalwrap">
                                <article>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="images/banner3.png" alt="">
                    <div class="txtoverlay">
                        <div class="centralise">
                            <div class="verticalwrap">
                                <article>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="images/banner4.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="txtoverlay">
                        <div class="centralise">
                            <div class="verticalwrap">
                                <article>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="images/banner5.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="txtoverlay">
                        <div class="centralise">
                            <div class="verticalwrap">
                                <article>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="images/banner6.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="txtoverlay">
                        <div class="centralise">
                            <div class="verticalwrap">
                                <article>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.flexslider').load({
    $('loadingDiv').remove();
  });
});
```

I think the problem is `$('.flexslider').load()` function is not working. Is there another way to work out this problem?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [This has been deprecated since 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: So should I download the latest version and it will work?

Comment: Contrary, you should use an old version if you want to use that. Or switch to `on.("load"...) ` syntax

Comment: @PrabhjotRai, he meant if you're using jQuery versions higher than version 1.7 this won't work because they removed it, in this [jQuery 1.8 Change Log](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) "*`#11733: Deprecate .load(), .unload(), and .error() methods`*", check this https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733

Comment: You shouldn't be guessing as to whether load is firing. Simply do a console.log and confirm that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The first element that hides incorrectly specified, if you take an element by the class you need to specify '.' if you specify the class.

Secondly, in the method "load" is transferred the closure and not the object

Try somethink like that

```
  $('.flexslider').load(function(){
      $('.loadingDiv').remove();
  });
```

Comment: Maybe u need to set load event to the last image. Cause in jquery says that "It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree". So u can do something like that: $( "ul.slides li:last-child img" ).load(function(){
      $('.loadingDiv').remove();
  });

Answer (score 0):

What you might be wanting is

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexslider">
    <div class="loadingDiv">
       somge gif here
    </div>                                              
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="duck.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="dog.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="boar.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="deer.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    var imagesToLoad=  $('.slides img').length,
        loaded = 0;
    $('.slides img').bind('load', function() {
        loaded++;
    console.log('Loaded '+loaded+'/'+imagesToLoad);
    if(loaded===imagesToLoad)
        $('.loadingDiv').remove();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Added an alternative that works. I used something similar with jQuery Promise before

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working. Are you using some dependencies?

Comment: None. Just jquery-1.12.

Comment: Have added all entire file. See if you can see any differences with your code

Comment: The console shows an error. `$ is not defined`. What should I do?

Comment: How have you included jquery in your project?

Comment: inside the `body` tag, `<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>` , towards the end of the `body` tag

Comment: Assuming that there is no error in loading the local jquery file, make sure its above the script tag for the above script. 
If yo're still looking to make this work, quickly try this.
-Replace the "layouts/scripts" link  to "code.jquery.com" (used in the answer above)
-Place this jquery script tag in the head section, before the body tag
-Place the hiding script in a script tag at the end, after the body tag

Answer (score 0):

Check this hope it can work.Load function expect data from server and replace with that div that you mentioned.I assume you do not want data from server so i have used simple index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".flexslider" ).load( "index.html" );
    setTimeout(function(){
   $(".loadingDiv").hide();
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: This works but the `.loadingDiv` is hidden before the `.flexslider` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation load event is not supposed to be used with divs.

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

If this html is inside your root document, I recommend to use DOMContentLoaded instead.

```
$(function() {
    $('.loadingDiv').remove();
});
```

If you are using $.load to fetch remote html. You can pass a callback

```
$('div').load(url, function() {
   $('.loadingDiv').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `loadingDiv` on `$(window).load` event. `$(window).load` executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images. Hope this will help you.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.loadingDiv').remove();
});
```

**Update:** For removing `loadingDiv` when `flexslider` div is completely loaded do like below. Count the number of images in `flexslider` and after loading the last image hide the `loadingDiv`.

```
var images = $('.flexslider img'),
    imagesLength = images.length;

images.load(function () {
    if (! --imagesLength) {
       $('.loadingDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but is a temporary solution. There are other elements too which take time for loading due to which the `.loadingDiv` waits for them too not for my `.slides` element. How can I do it for a particular div? Can I use css to hide this element?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working. Please let me know which dependencies are you using. Moreover, I used this code outside of document.load and inside too, still not working.

Comment: `jquery` only and I think you should remove `visibility:hidden` from the image in `loadingDiv`.  @PrabhjotRai

Comment: Not working. Should I add the code inside the document.ready?